# Lentidão em onPress - Pressable - React native

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Recentemente comecei a estudar React Native, e estou fazendo um APP de Agendamento!

Mas estou enfrentando um problema de lentidão quando eu clico em um **Pressable** dentro da listagem.

Primeiro eu fiz a listagem com FlatList, depois SectionList e por último tentei com VirtualizedList, para saber se o comportamento seria diferente, mas em todos os casos o resultado foi o mesmo

O problema é: *Quando eu clico em um botão da lista, chega a demorar uns 2 a 4 segundos para o método onPress ser chamado*

**segue trecho do código:**

```
const { servicoId, setServicoId } = useContext(AgendaContext);

const handlePress = useCallback(
  (servId: any) => {
    setServicoId((prev) => [...prev, servId]);
  },
  [servicoId]
);

<FlatList
  px={2}
  data={data}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <HStack space={[2, 3]} justifyContent="space-between">
      <VStack w="48" justifyContent="center">
        <Text color="coolGray.300">{item.serv_nome}</Text>
      </VStack>
      <Spacer />
      <VStack>
        <Text color="coolGray.300" alignSelf="flex-start">
          {item.serv_valor.toLocaleString("pt-br", {
            style: "currency",
            currency: "BRL",
          })}
        </Text>
        <Text fontSize="xs" color="yellow.400">
          {item.serv_tempo_execucao}min
        </Text>
      </VStack>
      <Spacer />
      <Pressable
        style={styles.button}
        size="sm"
        onPress={() => handlePress(item.serv_id)}
      >
        <Text color="background.dark">+</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </HStack>
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item) => `item-list-id-${item.serv_id.toString()}`}
/>
```

Sou muito grato se puderem me explicar o motivo da lentidão, e um meio no qual eu possa corrigir essa questão!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, com muita pesquisa descobri que devemos evitar usar funções anônimas em nossa FlatList

**Então, ao invés disso**

```
<FlatList
  px={2}
  data={data}
  renderItem={({ item }) => /*função anônima*/}
/>
```

**Eu fiz da seguinte forma:**

```
function renderItem(){
    return /*component*/
}

<FlatList
  px={2}
  data={data}
  renderItem={renderItem}
/>
```

E somente com essa mudança, os botões estão demorando menos para responder